# LaTeX error with moderncv

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, moderncv

I can't seem to figure where the problem is, and why the file wont compile. 
I'd be grateful if someone could help me.
Here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Anas}
\familyname{CHEIKH}
\title{Industrial Engineering student \newline ENIT - University Tunis El Manar}               % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\address{Rue Tilia, Av. Merdes}{8090, Kélibia, Tunisia}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{+216 20 826 448}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{cheikh_anas@live.fr}
\quote{\textbf{Looking for a 1-2 month entry-level internship starting in May 2014}}    


 \setlength{\quotewidth}{320 cm}


\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5 cm}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{\textbf{Education}}
\cventry{2013-2014\newline Tunisia}{National Engineering School of Tunis (ENIT– University Tunis El Manar)}{}{}{}{\textbf{Élève-ingénieur en Génie Industriel (B.Eng in Industrial Engineering)}
\newline Academic Background :
\begin{itemize}
\item Management of production systems.
\item Non conducting systems and procedures.
\item Energetic systems.
\item Procedures in polymeres and composites.
\end{itemize} 
}


% arguments 3 to 6 are optional
\cventry{2012-2013\newline Tunisia}{Preparatory institute of scientific and technical studies in \textit{La Marsa} (IPEST)}{}{}{}{\textbf{Advanced undergraduate studies in mathematics and physics in preparation for the
French and Tunisian nation-wide competitive entrance examinations for the 'Grandes Écoles'.}
 \newline Rank: 212th out of 5000 candidates in the Tunisian nation-wide examinations}
% arguments 3 to 6 are optional


\cventry{2010-2013\newline France}{Lycée du Parc in \textit{LYON}}{}{}{}{1st and 2nd year of preparatory school for engineering studies 
\newline Advanced undergraduate studies in Mathematics, Physics and Computer  Science. 
\newline 120 ECTS-credits  || A ECTS-grading scale.
\newline Tunisian Government Excellence Scholarship }
\cventry{2006-2010 \newline Tunisia}{Lycée Abdelaziz Belkhouja in \textit{Kélibia}}{\textsc{Tunisian Baccalaureate.}}{}{}{Rank : 47th out of 60 000 candidates in the Tunisian nation-wide examinations. \newline \textbf{Pioneer High School of Nabel.}}


\section{\textbf{Experience}}
\cventry{2013-2014 \newline Tunisia}{ENIT Junior Entreprise}{}{}{}{\textbf{Junior Member || Event Founder and Coordinator of “Almouhandes”} \newline Organization of the first Edition of the “Almouhandes” Event. \newline Team and budget management. }
\cventry{2013- Present \newline Tunisia}{IAESTE Tunisia \footnotesize{(The International Association for the Exchange of Students for Technical Experience)}}{}{}{}{\textbf{Junior Member} \newline (Job raising, Incoming, Outgoing ...)} 
\cventry{Oct-Dec 2013 \newline Tunisia}{ENIT Tunis \textbf{Mini project} : \textsc{Building a RepRap 3D-printer}}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{2012-2013 \newline Tunisia}{IPEST La Marsa \textbf{TIPE} : \textsc{Airplane modelization and flight simulation}}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{2011-2012\newline France}{Lycée du Parc LYON \textbf{TIPE} : \textsc{An application of the Galton-Watson Branching Process}}{}{}{}{}


%\section{Master thesis}
%\cvline{title}{\emph{Title}}
%\cvline{supervisors}{Supervisors}
%\cvline{description}{\small Short thesis abstract}


\section{\textbf{Skills}}
\cvline{Computer \newline Science}{C, Pascal, Caml, MATLAB, Maple, Photoshop, Microsoft office \& \LaTeX}{}{}
%\cvline{Programming}{C, Ada, Pascal}{}{}
%\cvline{Scientific}{Matlab, Maple}{}{}
%\cvline{Design}{ HTML, CSS}{}{}
%\cvline{OS}{Linux/Unix, Windows, DOS}{}{}

\section{\textbf{Languages}}
\cvlanguage{}{\textnormal{French}}{\textnormal{Full professional proficiency}}
\cvlanguage{}{\textnormal{English}}{\textnormal{Bilingual proficiency}}
\cvlanguage{}{\textnormal{Arabic}}{\textnormal{Native proficiency}}
\cvlanguage{}{\textnormal{German}}{\textnormal{Limited working proficiency}}


\section{\textbf{Interests}}

\cvline{Arts}{Photography, Music (Guitarist), Reading, Cinema.} 
\cvline{Sports}{Tennis. \textsc{Ex-Membre of the local Tennis Club ( T.C.K). Gold medal winner of the local tennis tournament}  \newline Jogging. Insanity fitness program ...}
\cvline{Others}{Development of human potentials. American TV shows.}
%\textbf{Voyage:} Hong Kong, Macau, Chine, Thailande,...

\closesection{}                   % needed to renewcommands
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} % change the symbol for lists



\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. For blocks of code, indent them by four spaces to activate syntax highlighting. Just select the entire block and click the button marked `{}` to do this.

Comment: The `\email` line should be `\email{cheikh\_anas@live.fr}`; the underscore character has a special meaning and it must be escaped for being used as such. Note also that when writing in English, no space should be used in front of colons and semicolons (it's different in French).

Comment: Also don't forget `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (or with the option corresponding to the file encoding) if you use accented characters in the input.

Answer (score 3):

The only error I get is the good old `missing $ inserted`, which is caused by the underscore in the email. Apparently `moderncv` isn't set up to handle underscores in the email address, but if you write `\_` it works fine, i.e.

```
\email{cheikh\_anas@live.fr}
```

instead of

```
\email{cheikh_anas@live.fr}
```

Comment: With an email like `\email{foo\_bar@baz.com}`, the compiled PDF links to bar@baz.com, skipping the foo_ part. Any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: Fixed by adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.